# Cloudinary secure_url to useState

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cloudinary

In next.js client component I am using the "CldUploadButton" from cloudinary. On the "onSuccess" event I am trying to loop over the upload result picking up the image "secure_url" and then assign them all the images state. For some reason I receive an empty array.
If someone has a better idea i'd be happy. Thanks.

```
export default function AddPost({ userId }) {
  const [images, setImages] = useState({});  

  return (
    <div>
      <form action={createPost} className="flex w-full">
        <input type="hidden" name="userId" defaultValue={userId} />
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" />

        <textarea
          type="text"
          name="content"
          placeholder="Content"
          className="p-8"
        />

        <CldUploadButton
          uploadPreset="bkklcz9f"
          options={{
            sources: ["local"],
            multiple: true,
            maxFiles: 4,
          }}      
        
          onSuccess={(result) => {
            let arr = [];
            const imageCount = Object.keys(images).length;
            for (let i = 0; i < imageCount; i++) {
              const data = {
                imageUrl: result[i].secure_url,
              };
              arr.push(data);
            }
            setImages(arr);
            
          }}
        />

        <input type="hidden" name="imageUrl" defaultValue={images} />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I see that you are iterating over images.length before you've set the value. So your iteration has a length of zero and an empty array should be expected.